# system.InvalidOperationException in entityframework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a problem when I update a line with a foreign key. The principle idea is to update a row in the database with a generic method but I have an exception when I save modification in the data base so I try to make the state of entity os modified but not the worker.

```
else if (ModeButtonVMCaracteristiquesType == ModeButtonVMCaracteristiqueType.EDITIONCaracteristiqueTypeItem)
{
    int idCaracteristiqueSelected = Convert.ToInt32(CaracteristiqueSelected.idCharacteristicItem);

    var LineModified = (from x in ImItemsModel.imtypeitems select x.imcharacteristicsitems).ToList();
    LineModified.ForEach(p => ImItemsModel.Entry(p).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified);
    var UpdateCaracteristicTypeItem = StaticGenericUpdate.UpadateRowInModel<imcharacteristicsitem>(ImItemsModel, "idCharacteristicItem", idCaracteristiqueSelected, "fk_idTypeItemIMCaracteristicsItems", fk_value, propertiesForModel, propertiesForView, this);

    ImItemsModel.SaveChanges();
```

So I have two models:

```
public partial class imcharacteristicsitem
{
    public imcharacteristicsitem()
    {
        this.imvaluesofitemscaracteristics = new HashSet<imvaluesofitemscaracteristic>();
    }

    public int idCharacteristicItem { get; set; }
    public string characteristicItem { get; set; }
    public string unitCaracteristicItem { get; set; }
    public int fk_idTypeItemIMCaracteristicsItems { get; set; }
    public byte[] typeValueCaracteristicItem { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<imvaluesofitemscaracteristic> imvaluesofitemscaracteristics { get; set; }
    public virtual imtypeitems imtypeitem { get; set; }
}
```

and:

```
public partial class imtypeitems
{
    public imtypeitems()
    {
        this.imcharacteristicsitems = new HashSet<imcharacteristicsitem>();
        this.imitems = new HashSet<imitem>();
    }

    public int idTypeItem { get; set; }
    public string DesignationTypeItem { get; set; }
    public byte[] SymbolTypeItem { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> MaxNumberConnectionsTypeItem { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<imcharacteristicsitem> imcharacteristicsitems { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<imitem> imitems { get; set; }
}
```

and the generic method is:

```
public static T UpadateRowInModel<T>(DbContext Model, string NameiD, int IdSelected, string NameFk_key  ,int fk_key, IList<PropertyInfo> propertiesModel, IList<PropertyInfo> propertiesView, VMCaracteristicType vm) where T : class
{
    T item = Model.Set<T>().Find(IdSelected);

    foreach (var property in propertiesModel)
    {
        if (propertiesView.Count != 0)
        {
            property.SetValue(item, propertiesView.FirstOrDefault(elem => elem.Name.Equals(property.Name)) == null ? null :
            propertiesView.FirstOrDefault(elem => elem.Name.Equals(property.Name)).GetValue(vm));
        }
        if (property.Name == NameiD)
        {
            property.SetValue(item, IdSelected);
        }
        if (property.Name == NameFk_key)
        {
            property.SetValue(item, null);
            Model.Entry(item).Property(NameFk_key).IsModified = false;
        }
    }

    return item;   
}
```

EDIT : 
so i realise that the probleme is the entity framework can't save because my table imtypeitems have a collection of caractéristique

```
  public virtual ICollection<imcharacteristicsitem> imcharacteristicsitems { get; set; }
```

so i must delet the row that i wish update it from this table and after that i will save so i can't delet the row of collection i try like this :

```
  var RowBeforupdate = ImItemsModel.imcharacteristicsitems.Include("imtypeitem").Single(row => row.idCharacteristicItem == idCaracteristiqueSelected);
                var UpdateCaracteristicTypeItem = StaticGenericUpdate.UpadateRowInModel<imcharacteristicsitem>(ImItemsModel, "idCharacteristicItem", idCaracteristiqueSelected, "fk_idTypeItemIMCaracteristicsItems", fk_value, propertiesForModel, propertiesForView, this);
                ImItemsModel.Entry(RowBeforupdate).CurrentValues.SetValues(UpdateCaracteristicTypeItem);
```

just a ps : i am not a expert in entity framework :(

Comment: What else is in the exception? TBH your generic method may be generic but to use it is not very friendly at all.

Comment: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

Comment: The error says You cannot assign null to the fk. Your fk is not nullable most likely.

Comment: it's not null that's why i don't understand the problem

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause for the FK null exception is that the FK entity property is processed/set in the `foreach` loop after the FK_ID property. So even if you change the FK_ID `IsModified` value to `false`, you're most likely later setting the `imtypeitem` property to null.

Also you are changing all model properties based on view properties; so if there's no particular view property you'll be setting the model property to null. This is seldom the thing you want to be doing in this scenario. Usually you want to change just the corresponding view properties and leave the other model properties unchanged.

So the `foreach` part of your generic method should look like this:

```
if (propertiesView.FirstOrDefault(elem => elem.Name.Equals(property.Name)) != null)
{
    property.SetValue(item, propertiesView.First(elem => elem.Name.Equals(property.Name)).GetValue(vm));
}
```

If you have certain properties that are part of view properties but you don't want them to be updated you can just skip them (using your `Nameid` and `NameFk_key`):

```
if(property.Name == NameiD || property.Name == NameFk_key)
    continue;
```

So the final form of the generic method might look something like this:

```
public static T UpadateRowInModel<T>(DbContext Model, string NameiD, int IdSelected, string NameFk_key  ,int fk_key, IList<PropertyInfo> propertiesModel, IList<PropertyInfo> propertiesView, VMCaracteristicType vm) where T : class
{
    T item = Model.Set<T>().Find(IdSelected);

    foreach (var property in propertiesModel)
    {
        if(property.Name == NameiD || property.Name == NameFk_key)
            continue;

        var viewP = propertiesView.FirstOrDefault(elem => elem.Name.Equals(property.Name));
        if (viewP != null)
        {
            property.SetValue(item, viewP.GetValue(vm));
        }            
    }

    return item;   
}
```

There's also a variation possible where you do a `foreach` on the `propertiesView`; also the parameters for the method can be adjusted.

On a sidenote: I'm not sure if

```
var LineModified = (from x in ImItemsModel.imtypeitems select x.imcharacteristicsitems).ToList();
LineModified.ForEach(p => ImItemsModel.Entry(p).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified);
```

does something useful, or if it does anything. The `p` in lambda is an `ICollection` of enity types and not a separate DB context entity. Not to mention that you want to set `Modified` state for ALL entities of type `imcharacteristicsitem`. Maybe you can explain the reason for this.

Comment: hello, thank u for all the details but i will edit the probleme just right now and if u can give me a solution :( @Marty

Comment: @WiemZarrouk please explain what you are trying to do. So far I understood following: there are `imtypeitems` and `imcharacteristicitems`. One `typeitem` 'contains' 0 or more `charactericitems` and each `characteristicitem` has a FK to a `typeitem`. Then you are updating one `characteristicitem`. What are you updating? 'Simple' properties (i.e. no IDs, no FKs, no relationships) or the other ones (i.e. IDs, FKs, relationships)? We can then go from there.

Comment: when i try to update a simple properties the entity framework catch that i must update the one ones  (i.e. IDs, FKs, relationships) so i try to delet one row of collection charactericitems and after that i can update but i can't remove a row from collection charactericitems in imtypeitems !!! i don't know why

Comment: @WiemZarrouk if you are updating just the simple properties, there's no need to update the IDs, FKs or relationships. Have you tried using my generic method? What was the result?